# Convergence of series $\sum \frac{1}{(p^n-q^n)}$, where $0<q<p$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum \frac{1}{(p^n-q^n)}$, where $0<q<p$.

$\sum \frac{1}{(p^n-q^n)}=\sum \frac{1}{(p-q)(p^{n-1}+p^{n-2}q+\dots+q^{n-1})}$
$\leq\frac{1}{p-q} \sum \frac{1}{nq^{n-1}}$

So now how to prove the series $\sum \frac{1}{nq^{n-1}}$ converges or not?

Comment: Think about integrating $\sum x^n$ with $|x|<1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{p^n-q^n}}{\frac1{p^n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p^n}{p^n-q^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1-\left(\frac qp\right)^n}=1.$$Therefore\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{p^n-q^n}\text{ converges}&\iff\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{p^n}\text{ converges}\\&\iff p>1.\end{align}